# Capturar resultados usando HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, foreach, html-tags, html-agility-pack

Estou usando esse código para buscar resultados usando o Html Agility Pack. Ele é assim:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(texto);
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
        string Texto = reader.ReadToEnd();

        var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(Texto);
        var links = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[contains(text(),'2')][@href]");

        if (links != null)
        {
            foreach (HtmlNode link in links)
            {
                var href = link.Attributes["href"].Value;
                MessageBox.Show(href);
            }
        }
```

A ideia do código é: Procurar por uma tag como essa:

```
<a href="/t439-teste">2</a>
```

O código que eu tenho funcionou corretamente e pega os resultados. O problema é que ele está capturando os resultados que tenham 2 em seu conjunto, eu quero que só capture apenas os que têm EXATAMENTE o 2, ele sozinho. Tem como?

Desde já agradeço pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Assim será que não funciona?

```
var links = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a").where(x => x.innerHTML == "2");
```